# PHP syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php

I want to make the text red if username == user_id but it gives me a syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF). my code:

```
foreach ($dag as $taak) {
    echo '<li' if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $taak['username']){ echo 'style="color:red"';}'>'.$taak['taak_naam'].' - '.$taak['username'].'</li>';
}
```

anyone any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
echo '<li';

if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $taak['username']){ 

echo ' style="color:red"';

}

echo '>'.$taak['taak_naam'] . ' - '  .$taak['username'] . '</li>';
```

Comment: why downvote may i know

Comment: You're still missing a whitespace before the style attribute.

Comment: tanqq for point that @Hienz

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix decisions (`if ...`) with output. Prepare everything before echoing:

```
foreach ($dag as $taak) {
    // Don't add color by default
    $style = '';
    // Special color for special entries
    if ($_SESSION['user_id'] == $taak['username']) {
        $style = ' style="color: red;"';
    }

    // Make sure HTML special characters in $taak['username'] do not break the HTML
    $username  = htmlspecialchars($taak['username']);

    // Display
    echo("<li{$style}>{$taak['taak_naam']} - {$username}</li>");
}
```

By surrounding the [string in double quotes (`"`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), PHP [recognizes variable names](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) inside it and replaces them with their values.

The [curly braces (`{` and `}`) around the array values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) tell PHP the variable is `$taak['taak_naam']`, otherwise it finds only `$taak` and it outputs `Array['taak_naam']` (which is not what we want).

If a value you use to create HTML content might contain characters that are special in HTML then you must encode those characters using their correct HTML definition. The PHP function [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) knows how to do it.

It encodes `<`, `>`, `&` and `"` (these are HTML breakers if they are not encoded properly). If you need to encode all the symbols that are defined in HTML as "character entities" you can use the PHP function [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use **if** between the strings

```
foreach ($dag as $taak) {
        $style='';
        if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $taak['username'])
          $style='style="color:red"';
        echo "<li {$style}> {$taak['taak_naam']} - {$taak['username']}</li>";
    }

                 ****OR****


 foreach ($dag as $taak) { ?>
   <li <?php if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $taak['username'])
      echo 'style="color:red"'; ?> >
      <?= $taak['taak_naam'].' - '.$taak['username']; ?>
   </li>';
  <?php
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Forgot the semicolon.

```
foreach ($dag as $taak) {
echo '<li';
if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $taak['username']) {
    echo ' style="color:red"';
}
echo '>'.$taak['taak_naam'].' - '.$taak['username'].'</li>';
}
```

Comment: This will still give you a syntax error, if in this context is not allowed (comment was made before the answer edit)

Comment: Why isn't it allowed? I guess it should work.

Comment: Look at the answer before the edit

Answer (score -1):

You can use the short if syntax, the long syntax is not allowed in this context:

```
    foreach ($dag as $taak) {
        echo '<li' . (($_SESSION['user_id'] == $taak['username']) ? ' style="color:red"' : '') . '>' .$taak['taak_naam'] . ' - ' . $taak['username'].'</li>';
    }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as *"the short if syntax"*. [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) is a control-flow statement, [`?:`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is an operator. They are completely different things. A statement does something (a control-flow statement decides what code branch to take based on a condition), an operator joins two sub-expressions into a larger expression. An expression has a value (it can be computed).